# How to perform the mv equivalent of yes | cp -rf on directories?

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, command-line-interface, mv

Using the below directory tree as an example, what is the best way to move the contents of `directory/folderA` to `directory`.

How to overwrite a file if a file with the same name exists in the destination, for example: `directory/folderA/2017/06/info.log` and `directory/2017/06/info.log`.

```
directory
|-- folderA
|   |-- 2017
|   |   |-- 06
|   |
|   |-- 2016
|   |   |-- 12
|   |   |-- 11
|   |   |-- 10
|
|-- 2017
|   |-- 04
|   |-- 05
|   |-- 06
|
|-- 2016
|   |
```

Comment: You can add the `-f` (force) option to `mv` to overwrite files without asking.

Comment: No that is incorrect, that does not preserve anything in the destination. The overwrite should only happen IF a file with the same name exists.

Comment: Have you checked RSync yet? I don't think `mv` suits your requirements.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen The desired outcome can be achieved using `yes | cp -rf`, the reason why using `mv` is ideal because it doesn't cause the data to be rewritten again (which takes a long time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with `cp -l` (`--link`, *hard link files instead of copying*):

```
cp -rfl folderA .
rm -rf folderA
```

The `mv` just moves i.e. renames the directory to be your `directory`. For moving files within the same file system `mv` uses `rename()` system call. If the source and target were on different files systems, `mv` would use `cp` and `rm` to accomplish the move, but still first removes the destination, copies hard linked files (`-R`) but doesn't follow symbolic links (`-P`):

> ```
> rm -f destination_path && \
> cp -pRP source_file destination && \
> rm -rf source_file
> ```

While you can't change this behavior of `mv`, the `cp` command itself is more flexible, and you really should use it, instead. With `cp`, the `-f` causes removing and creation of single files inside the destination instead of removing the whole destination first.

The `cp` is also limited as it can only either overwrite (`-f`), preserver (`-n`) or ask (`-i`). If you need to compare the files before deciding which one to keep, you'd need `rsync`.

If you still need to use `rename()` system call but accomplish your goal of merging the directories as desired, you'd need to write a script that invokes individual `rename()`s for single files.

Comment: The reason why `mv` would be strongly preferred is because it's a lot of data which would take days to `cp`.

Comment: I added the solution for you with `cp -l`. It does what you need. Now, the best solution appears first and the rest of the answer explains you why you simply can't use `mv`, what other options you have, and why they all may be more complicated.

Comment: @Dave To clarify, `cp -l` doesn't actually copy the *data*, it just makes the same file appear in the new directory as well as the old. By doing first `cp -l` and then `rm`, you are doing very nearly the exact same thing as the `mv` command, but you get access to the options for `cp` instead.

Comment: Good additional explanation for term _hard link_, Jenny!

Answer (score 1):

First, I created your directory tree with

```
[root@localhost /tmp]# mkdir -pv directory/folderA/2017/06 directory/folderA/2016/{10..12} directory/2017/{04..06} directory/2016
```

Then I created your example files with:

```
[root@localhost /tmp]# touch directory/{,folderA}/2017/06/info.log
```

Last, I used rsync with the --delete-after to move instead of rsync's default behavior which would create a copy instead:

```
[root@localhost /tmp]# rsync --delete-after -a directory/folderA/ directory
```

Note: the trailing '/' after the source directory (ie. directory/folderA/ as opposed to directory/folderA) is required if you want the directories to be deleted after they are copied.

Of course, if you really wanted to type mv to obtain the desired behavior you could create a custom shell function.  I'm not advocating this, but it is possible.  Sloppy, but possible.

Here's a custom function you could add to your ~/.bashrc:

```
function mv() {
    if [[ "$@" =~ .*--delete-after.*-av*.* ]]; then
            rsync $@
    else
            command mv $@
    fi; }
```

Then invoke the updated ~/.bashrc by logging out and logging back in -or- by typing:

```
[root@localhost /tmp]# exec bash
```

Now you can test your custom function with either:

```
[root@localhost /tmp]# mv --delete-after -av directory/folderA/ directory
```

to get verbose output,

or with:

```
[root@localhost /tmp]# mv --delete-after -a directory/folderA/ directory
```

to receive only errors if any are encountered.

As an aside, you can also avoid piping yes to the cp -rf command by issuing your cp command with a preceding backslash like this:

```
[root@localhost /tmp]# \cp -rf directory/folderA/* directory/
```

The reason you are piping yes is you likely have an alias for the cp command in your ~/.bashrc such as this:

```
[root@localhost /tmp]# alias cp='cp -i'
```

which you can verify by typing:

```
[root@localhost /tmp]# type cp
```